# Anchor link not working when clicked

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, anchor

Sooo.. I've got this navigation on the frontpage. I'm trying make it link to an anchor on another page.

[www.oddfuse.com](http://oddfuse.com)

This is the anchor link:

```
<a class="hover" title="Skills" href="/page#skills">
```

As you can see, it does not redirect to the specified page.

However it *does* work when typed directly into the address bar:

[www.oddfuse.com/page#skills](http://oddfuse.com/page#skills)

This also works:

```
<a class="hover" title="Skills" href="/page">
```

But with the hash, I get no response whatsoever.

Any ideas on how I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so it turned out that it was the jQuery Mobile somehow messing with the anchor tags.

I needed to put `data-ajax="false"` in the link, and it now works perfectly. TMYK.

**Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446055/how-to-get-anchor-links-to-work-in-jquery-mobile)**

Answer (score 0):

can you try including the file extension?
i.e.

```
<a class="hover" title="Skills" href="/page.html#skills" />
```

I'm wondering if it thinks the # is part of a file name that can't be found.

Comment: Tried this, but it does not seem to be working either

Answer (score 0):

If you want a link to jump a specific location on a different page, you'll need to replace #anchor with the full URL for the target page, similar to:

```
<a class="hover" title="Skills" href="http://oddfuse.com/page/#skills">
```