# Anchor is not working fine in Jquery mobile page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I read [How to get Anchor Links to work in Jquery Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446055/how-to-get-anchor-links-to-work-in-jquery-mobile/14779384#14779384) , but it is not what I want.

I have the below page, and I have two anchor for this page.

it is weird that  I copy my file location+#zhuaguirule to the browser, it is not showing the correct part as expected. and if I type ENTER in firefox again, it shows the second part.

Why is that? I also tried deploy this page to PROD env and the mobile browser did not bring me to the second part either. I need to have a URL that bring me to the second part.

This is my page of JQuery mobile

```
<div data-role="page" id="rule">
    <div data-role="content" id="wodirule">  <!--this is one part-->
     <h2>GAME RULE 1</h2>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li>....</li>
            <li>....</li>
        </ul>
     </div>  
     <br><br>    

    <div data-role="content" id="zhuaguirule"><!--this is the other part-->
    <h2>GAME RULE 2</h2> 
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                <li>....</li>
                <li>....</li>                   
            </ul>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"> 
                <li>...</li>
                <li>...</li>
            </ul>

    </div>

   <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
      <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="PAGE1.html" data-icon="home">....</a></li>
            <li><a href="PAGE2.html" data-icon="home">....</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @gibsonman507 sorry for the typo, I did not have comment in my real page, I just add it in the question, and I have corrected this in the question now

Comment: I think you should use *location+#rule* instead of *location+#zhuaguirule*, i.e. the id of the page (*data-role=page*), instead of the id ot the content (*data-role=content*).

Comment: @sergioFC , but the #rule is just shows the first part, I need the second part to be brought in some case!

Comment: Not sure if you can do that without making two differents jqm pages or without toggling the visibility of each content.

Comment: @sergioFC ,no , I need to contain all the content in one single page that user can see them all. But at the very first time he should be brought to some  anchor, determined by the URL.