# Unable to connect external HTML file using jQuery button link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried to connect to a HTML file in the same directory using href, but it gives me an error loading page.

It gives the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Nadeesha/Desktop/Collect/FounderR.html. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

What can I do to solve this?

```
<a data-theme="d" data-corners="false" data-role="button" href="FounderR.html">
       <img src="images/icons/round/64x64/entr.gif" alt="entr" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto">
        Founder
</a>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery? It's a basic HTML anchor.

Comment: The above code will work perfectly. There is no role of Jquery in the code given above. IS your Founder.html loading correctly as a standalone file?

Comment: I am building a SPA using jquery,javaScript and html.Mostly I have used id to jump from one section to another,Here I need to access a external html file,but the application does not allow to do that

Comment: @Akhil yes,It works perfectly when I run it alone

Comment: Can you be specific when you actually get the error?
After Clicking on Founder? OR while loading the page which refers to founder.html?

Comment: When I click on the founder application gives the error

Comment: @Nadeesha do you happen to be working with jQuery Mobile?

Comment: I have checked the console and it shows                              XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Nadeesha/Desktop/Collect/FounderR.html. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Oh ,I have check the application with other browsers then it works perfectly,First I have test it using chrome and it doesn't work but when I test it using firefox its working

Comment: @Jerreck yes I am using jquery mobile,What is the reason for this error?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["How to get Anchor Links to work in Jquery Mobile?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446055/how-to-get-anchor-links-to-work-in-jquery-mobile)

Comment: @Nadeesha add data-ajax="false" to your anchors and they should begin working.

Comment: @Jerreck thank you very much! it's working,Now the application working fine on chrome too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using chrome, and i assume you are, You will face CORS problems when working o localhost.

Ill recommend you to read this:

https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin?hl=es

Comment: Nadeesha's files are in the same directory as the resource that's requesting them.  This wouldn't violate the same-origin policy.

Comment: Yes it would. See the url he is using. Please read the document i´ve left on the comment.

Comment: Ah, made sense after I read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208530/xmlhttprequest-origin-null-is-not-allowed-access-control-allow-origin-for-file). My bad.