# Link is not going to href location on click

Tags: jquery, html

I have a jQuery Mobile page with the following header:

```
<div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
    <a href="index.html#adminhome" data-icon="home" data-theme="b">Home</a>
    <h3>Head</h3>
    <a href="index.html" data-icon="delete" data-theme="b">Logout</a>
</div>
```

*index.html* is a different page. However, when I click on the "Home" link nothing happens.  If I remove the `#adminhome`, it does bring me to *index.html*, so that appears to be the issue.

There are no JS errors, and when I right click and select "open in new browser" it opens in the correct location. I have tried it both in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446055/how-to-get-anchor-links-to-work-in-jquery-mobile maybe?

Comment: What is the complete URL in your address bar when you try this?

Comment: is there a `#` in the url? if you are on index.html and want to go to index.html#, if you already have a hash then the page wouldn't necessarily refresh ([this might help](http://lea.verou.me/2011/05/change-url-hash-without-page-jump/) depending on the application)

Comment: full url of where im trying to get to (in a local environement) is http://localhost/gm/index.html#adminhome      ... the page i am on (stats.html) and (index.html) are in the same directory

Comment: ... bit more info here.  The issue appears to be related to the jquery mobile.  When I remove the jquery script and it reverts to a normal link, the link opens fine.  It must be the jquery interpreting the "#" to be the id of an object.  I wonder then how you might escape a "#" in a link in jquery